# How to split Nginx event into two separate events

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

In Nginx, I've a file called x_event.js that has two methods, method A() and methodB() which return stringified JSON objects.

```
js_include path2nginxconf/njs/x_event.js;
js_set $methodA methodA;
js_set $methodB methodB;
log_format x_event escape=none js_set $methodA $methodB;
```

This works well, however, it concatenates the two JSON strings into a single event log. I would like to have them output as two separate events. Is this possible and how? Thanks.

Currently, I see:

```
{outputA}{outputB}
```

Expected:

```
{outputA}
{outputB}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting the following configuration:

```
js_set $methodA methodA;
js_set $methodB methodB;
log_format x_event_A escape=none $methodA;
log_format x_event_B escape=none $methodB;
access_log ~/logs/access.log x_event_A;
access_log ~/logs/access.log x_event_B;
```